# Mujoco environment to gymnasium environment

Tags: openai-gym, mujoco

The problem I am facing is that when I am training my agent using PPO, the environment doesn't render using Pygame, but when I manually step through the environment using random actions, the rendering works fine. Here is my code for the environment,

```
import gymnasium as gym
from gymnasium import spaces
import numpy as np
import mujoco
import glfw
import cv2
import pygame

xml = """  
  -->

  <mujoco model="Humanoid">
    <option timestep="0.005"/>

    <visual>
      <map force="0.1" zfar="30"/>
      <rgba haze="0.15 0.25 0.35 1"/>
      <global offwidth="2560" offheight="1440" elevation="-20" azimuth="120"/>
    </visual>

    <statistic center="0 0 0.7"/>

    <asset>
      <texture type="skybox" builtin="gradient" rgb1=".3 .5 .7" rgb2="0 0 0" width="32" height="512"/>
      <texture name="body" type="cube" builtin="flat" mark="cross" width="128" height="128" rgb1="0.8 0.6 0.4" rgb2="0.8 0.6 0.4" markrgb="1 1 1" random="0.01"/>
      <material name="body" texture="body" texuniform="true" rgba="0.8 0.6 .4 1"/>
      <texture name="grid" type="2d" builtin="checker" width="512" height="512" rgb1=".1 .2 .3" rgb2=".2 .3 .4"/>
      <material name="grid" texture="grid" texrepeat="1 1" texuniform="true" reflectance=".2"/>
    </asset>

    <default>
      <motor ctrlrange="-1 1" ctrllimited="true"/>
      <default class="body">

        <!-- geoms -->
        <geom type="capsule" condim="1" friction=".7" solimp=".9 .99 .003" solref=".015 1" material="body"/>
        <default class="thigh">
          <geom size=".06"/>
        </default>
        <default class="shin">
          <geom fromto="0 0 0 0 0 -.3"  size=".049"/>
        </default>
        <default class="foot">
          <geom size=".027"/>
          <default class="foot1">
            <geom fromto="-.07 -.01 0 .14 -.03 0"/>
          </default>
          <default class="foot2">
            <geom fromto="-.07 .01 0 .14  .03 0"/>
          </default>
        </default>
        <default class="arm_upper">
          <geom size=".04"/>
        </default>
        <default class="arm_lower">
          <geom size=".031"/>
        </default>
        <default class="hand">
          <geom type="sphere" size=".04"/>
        </default>

        <!-- joints -->
        <joint type="hinge" damping=".2" stiffness="1" armature=".01" limited="true" solimplimit="0 .99 .01"/>
        <default class="joint_big">
          <joint damping="5" stiffness="10"/>
          <default class="hip_x">
            <joint range="-30 10"/>
          </default>
          <default class="hip_z">
            <joint range="-60 35"/>
          </default>
          <default class="hip_y">
            <joint axis="0 1 0" range="-150 20"/>
          </default>
          <default class="joint_big_stiff">
            <joint stiffness="20"/>
          </default>
        </default>
        <default class="knee">
          <joint pos="0 0 .02" axis="0 -1 0" range="-160 2"/>
        </default>
        <default class="ankle">
          <joint range="-50 50"/>
          <default class="ankle_y">
            <joint pos="0 0 .08" axis="0 1 0" stiffness="6"/>
          </default>
          <default class="ankle_x">
            <joint pos="0 0 .04" stiffness="3"/>
          </default>
        </default>
        <default class="shoulder">
          <joint range="-85 60"/>
        </default>
        <default class="elbow">
          <joint range="-100 50" stiffness="0"/>
        </default>
      </default>
    </default>

    <worldbody>
      <geom name="floor" size="0 0 .05" type="plane" material="grid" condim="3"/>
      <light name="spotlight" mode="targetbodycom" target="torso" diffuse=".8 .8 .8" specular="0.3 0.3 0.3" pos="0 -6 4" cutoff="30"/>
      <body name="torso" pos="0 0 1.282" childclass="body">
        <light name="top" pos="0 0 2" mode="trackcom"/>
        <camera name="back" pos="-3 0 1" xyaxes="0 -1 0 1 0 2" mode="trackcom"/>
        <camera name="side" pos="0 -3 1" xyaxes="1 0 0 0 1 2" mode="trackcom"/>
        <freejoint name="root"/>
        <geom name="torso" fromto="0 -.08 0 0 .08 0" size=".08"/>
        <geom name="waist_upper" fromto="-.01 -.06 -.12 -.01 .06 -.12" size=".06"/>
        <body name="head" pos="0 0 .19">
          <geom name="head" type="sphere" size=".09"/>
          <camera name="egocentric" pos=".09 0 0" xyaxes="0 -1 0 .1 0 1" fovy="80"/>
        </body>
        <body name="waist_lower" pos="-.01 0 -.26">
          <geom name="waist_lower" fromto="0 -.06 0 0 .06 0" size=".06"/>
          <joint name="abdomen_z" pos="0 0 .065" axis="0 0 1" range="-45 45" class="joint_big_stiff"/>
          <joint name="abdomen_y" pos="0 0 .065" axis="0 1 0" range="-75 30" class="joint_big"/>
          <body name="pelvis" pos="0 0 -.165">
            <joint name="abdomen_x" pos="0 0 .1" axis="1 0 0" range="-35 35" class="joint_big"/>
            <geom name="butt" fromto="-.02 -.07 0 -.02 .07 0" size=".09"/>
            <body name="thigh_right" pos="0 -.1 -.04">
              <joint name="hip_x_right" axis="1 0 0" class="hip_x"/>
              <joint name="hip_z_right" axis="0 0 1" class="hip_z"/>
              <joint name="hip_y_right" class="hip_y"/>
              <geom name="thigh_right" fromto="0 0 0 0 .01 -.44" class="thigh"/>
              <body name="shin_right" pos="0 .01 -.4">
                <joint name="knee_right" class="knee"/>
                <geom name="shin_right" class="shin"/>
                <body name="foot_right" pos="0 0 -.39">
                  <joint name="ankle_y_right" class="ankle_y"/>
                  <joint name="ankle_x_right" class="ankle_x" axis="1 0 .5"/>
                  <geom name="foot1_right" class="foot1"/>
                  <geom name="foot2_right" class="foot2"/>
                </body>
              </body>
            </body>
            <body name="thigh_left" pos="0 .1 -.04">
              <joint name="hip_x_left" axis="-1 0 0" class="hip_x"/>
              <joint name="hip_z_left" axis="0 0 -1" class="hip_z"/>
              <joint name="hip_y_left" class="hip_y"/>
              <geom name="thigh_left" fromto="0 0 0 0 -.01 -.44" class="thigh"/>
              <body name="shin_left" pos="0 -.01 -.4">
                <joint name="knee_left" class="knee"/>
                <geom name="shin_left" fromto="0 0 0 0 0 -.3" class="shin"/>
                <body name="foot_left" pos="0 0 -.39">
                  <joint name="ankle_y_left" class="ankle_y"/>
                  <joint name="ankle_x_left" class="ankle_x" axis="-1 0 -.5"/>
                  <geom name="foot1_left" class="foot1"/>
                  <geom name="foot2_left" class="foot2"/>
                </body>
              </body>
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
        <body name="right_upper_arm" pos="0 -.17 .06">
          <joint name="right_shoulder1" axis="2 1 1"  class="shoulder"/>
          <joint name="right_shoulder2" axis="0 -1 1" class="shoulder"/>
          <geom name="right_upper_arm" fromto="0 0 0 .16 -.16 -.16" class="arm_upper"/>
          <body name="right_lower_arm" pos=".18 -.18 -.18">
            <joint name="right_elbow" axis="0 -1 1" class="elbow"/>
            <geom name="right_lower_arm" fromto=".01 .01 .01 .17 .17 .17" class="arm_lower"/>
            <body name="right_hand" pos=".18 .18 .18">
              <geom name="right_hand" zaxis="1 1 1" class="hand" size=".09"/>
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
        <body name="left_upper_arm" pos="0 .17 .06">
          <joint name="left_shoulder1" axis="-2 1 -1" class="shoulder"/>
          <joint name="left_shoulder2" axis="0 -1 -1"  class="shoulder"/>
          <geom name="left_upper_arm" fromto="0 0 0 .16 .16 -.16" class="arm_upper"/>
          <body name="left_lower_arm" pos=".18 .18 -.18">
            <joint name="left_elbow" axis="0 -1 -1" class="elbow"/>
            <geom name="left_lower_arm" fromto=".01 -.01 .01 .17 -.17 .17" class="arm_lower"/>
            <body name="left_hand" pos=".18 -.18 .18">
              <geom name="left_hand" zaxis="1 -1 1" class="hand" size=".09"/>       
            </body>
          </body>
        </body>
      </body>

        <geom name="ring_floor" type="box" size="3 3 0.1" pos="0 0 -0.05" rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>

        <!-- Front ropes -->
        <geom name="front_rope1" type="capsule" fromto="-3 3 0.5 3 3 0.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="front_rope2" type="capsule" fromto="-3 3 1 3 3 1" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="front_rope3" type="capsule" fromto="-3 3 1.5 3 3 1.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>

        <!-- Back ropes -->
        <geom name="back_rope1" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 0.5 3 -3 0.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="back_rope2" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 1 3 -3 1" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="back_rope3" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 1.5 3 -3 1.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>

        <!-- Left ropes -->
        <geom name="left_rope1" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 0.5 -3 3 0.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="left_rope2" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 1 -3 3 1" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="left_rope3" type="capsule" fromto="-3 -3 1.5 -3 3 1.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>

        <!-- Right ropes -->
        <geom name="right_rope1" type="capsule" fromto="3 -3 0.5 3 3 0.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="right_rope2" type="capsule" fromto="3 -3 1 3 3 1" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
        <geom name="right_rope3" type="capsule" fromto="3 -3 1.5 3 3 1.5" size="0.05" rgba="1 1 1 1"/>


        <geom name="corner1" type="cylinder" size="0.1 1" pos="3 3 1" rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
        <geom name="corner2" type="cylinder" size="0.1 1" pos="-3 3 1" rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
        <geom name="corner3" type="cylinder" size="0.1 1" pos="3 -3 1" rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
        <geom name="corner4" type="cylinder" size="0.1 1" pos="-3 -3 1" rgba="0 0 0 1"/>

    </worldbody>

    <contact>
      <exclude body1="waist_lower" body2="thigh_right"/>
      <exclude body1="waist_lower" body2="thigh_left"/>
    </contact>

    <tendon>
      <fixed name="hamstring_right" limited="true" range="-0.3 2">
        <joint joint="hip_y_right" coef=".5"/>
        <joint joint="knee_right" coef="-.5"/>
      </fixed>
      <fixed name="hamstring_left" limited="true" range="-0.3 2">
        <joint joint="hip_y_left" coef=".5"/>
        <joint joint="knee_left" coef="-.5"/>
      </fixed>
    </tendon>

    <actuator>
      <motor name="abdomen_y"       gear="40"  joint="abdomen_y"/>
      <motor name="abdomen_z"       gear="40"  joint="abdomen_z"/>
      <motor name="abdomen_x"       gear="40"  joint="abdomen_x"/>
      <motor name="hip_x_right"     gear="40"  joint="hip_x_right"/>
      <motor name="hip_z_right"     gear="40"  joint="hip_z_right"/>
      <motor name="hip_y_right"     gear="120" joint="hip_y_right"/>
      <motor name="knee_right"      gear="80"  joint="knee_right"/>
      <motor name="ankle_x_right"   gear="20"  joint="ankle_x_right"/>
      <motor name="ankle_y_right"   gear="20"  joint="ankle_y_right"/>
      <motor name="hip_x_left"      gear="40"  joint="hip_x_left"/>
      <motor name="hip_z_left"      gear="40"  joint="hip_z_left"/>
      <motor name="hip_y_left"      gear="120" joint="hip_y_left"/>
      <motor name="knee_left"       gear="80"  joint="knee_left"/>
      <motor name="ankle_x_left"    gear="20"  joint="ankle_x_left"/>
      <motor name="ankle_y_left"    gear="20"  joint="ankle_y_left"/>
      <motor name="right_shoulder1" gear="20"  joint="right_shoulder1"/>
      <motor name="right_shoulder2" gear="20"  joint="right_shoulder2"/>
      <motor name="right_elbow"     gear="40"  joint="right_elbow"/>
      <motor name="left_shoulder1"  gear="20"  joint="left_shoulder1"/> 
      <motor name="left_shoulder2"  gear="20"  joint="left_shoulder2"/>
      <motor name="left_elbow"      gear="40"  joint="left_elbow"/>
    </actuator>

    <keyframe>
      <!--
      The values below are split into rows for readibility:
        torso position
        torso orientation
        spinal
        right leg
        left leg
        arms
      -->
      <key name="squat" qpos="0 0 0.596
                              0.988015 0 0.154359 0
                              0 0.4 0
                              -0.25 -0.5 -2.5 -2.65 -0.8 0.56
                              -0.25 -0.5 -2.5 -2.65 -0.8 0.56
                              0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
      <key name="stand_on_left_leg" qpos="0 0 1.21948
                                          0.971588 -0.179973 0.135318 -0.0729076
                                          -0.0516 -0.202 0.23
                                          -0.24 -0.007 -0.34 -1.76 -0.466 -0.0415
                                          -0.08 -0.01 -0.37 -0.685 -0.35 -0.09
                                          0.109 -0.067 -0.7 -0.05 0.12 0.16"/>
    </keyframe>
  </mujoco>
"""

target_stance = [0, 0, 1.2, 
                0.5, 0, 0, 0,   # torso orientation
                0, 0, 0,        # spine
                -0.5, 0.2, -1.5, -1.7, -0.5, 0.3,   # right leg
                0.5, -0.2, -1.5, -1.7, -0.5, -0.3,  # left leg 
                0.1, -0.1, -0.7, -0.1, 0.2, 0.3]    # arms

class BoxingEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        # Load the MuJoCo model from XML string
        self.model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_string(xml)
        self.sim = mujoco.MjData(self.model)

        # Define action and observation spaces
        num_actuators = self.model.nu
        num_observations = self.model.nq  # This is just an example; adjust as needed
        self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=-1, high=1, shape=(num_actuators,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(num_observations,), dtype=np.float32)

        self.renderer = mujoco.Renderer(model = self.model, height=720, width=1366)
        self.done = False
        self.fallen = bool(self.sim.qpos[2] < 0.3)
        self.timestep = 0

        num_observations = len(self._get_observation())
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=-np.inf, high=np.inf, shape=(num_observations,), dtype=np.float32)

        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1366, 720))  # Adjust the resolution as needed


    def step(self, action):
        self.timestep += 1

        # Apply the action to the environment
        self.sim.ctrl[:] = action
        mujoco.mj_step(self.model, self.sim)

        # Get the observation, reward, done, and info
        observation = self._get_observation()
        reward = self._get_reward()
        done = self._get_done()
        self.done = done
        trunctuated = False
        info = {}

        return observation, reward, done, trunctuated, info

    def reset(self, seed = None, **kwargs):
        # Set initial conditions
        init_qpos = [0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...] 
        init_qvel = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

        # Reset MuJoCo
        self.sim = mujoco.MjData(self.model)
        mujoco.mj_forward(self.model, self.sim)

        # Get observation 
        obs = self._get_observation()
        mujoco.mj_forward(self.model, self.sim)

        reset_info = {}  # This can be populated with any reset-specific info if needed
        return obs, reset_info


    def render(self, mode='human'):
        self.renderer.update_scene(self.sim)
        
        img = self.renderer.render()
        pygame_img = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(np.transpose(img, (1, 0, 2)))
        self.screen.blit(pygame_img, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

        if self.timestep >= 20 * 60: # 20 secs at 60 fps    
            obs = self.reset()
            self.timestep = 0

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()


    def _get_observation(self):
      # Joint positions
      qpos = self.sim.qpos
      
      # Joint velocities
      qvel = self.sim.qvel

      contact_forces = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.array(self.sim.cfrc_ext)), axis=1)))
      
      # Concatenate and return as a single observation vector
      observation = np.concatenate([qpos, qvel, [contact_forces]])
      
      return observation


    def _get_reward(self):
        stance_diff = np.linalg.norm(self.sim.qpos - target_stance)
        if self.fallen:
            return -10
        else: 
            return 0
        return -stance_diff

    def _get_done(self):
        if self.fallen:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def sample_random_action(self):

      # Get action bounds
      action_low = self.action_space.low
      action_high = self.action_space.high
      
      # Sample random action as numpy array
      action = np.random.uniform(low=action_low, high=action_high)
      
      return action

class BoxingEnvWrapper(gym.Wrapper):

  def __init__(self, env):
    super().__init__(env)
  
  def reset(self, seed=None, **kwargs):
    obs = self.env.reset()
    return obs
  
  def step(self, action):
    obs, reward, done, trunctuated, info = self.env.step(action)
    
    # Calculate stance reward
    stance_diff = np.linalg.norm(self.env.sim.qpos - target_stance)
    reward = -stance_diff
    
    return obs, reward, trunctuated, done, info
  
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

env = BoxingEnvWrapper(BoxingEnv())
from gymnasium.envs.registration import register

register(
    id='BoxingEnv-v2',
    entry_point='final_boxing:BoxingEnv', 
)


from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecEnvWrapper

    
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: BoxingEnvWrapper(BoxingEnv())])

model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
```

I tried using other forms of rendering such as opencv but it doesnt even render at all unless I use pygame. I expect the code to render the mujoco environment while training so I can check in on the progress but the code just displays a black screen.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering in human mode. As your env is a mujocoEnv type, this rendering mode should raise a mujoco rendering window.
If you want an image to use as source for your pygame object, you should render the mujocoEnv using rgb_array mode, which will return you the environment's camera image in RGB format.